# Searching related works for papers

Tags: compilers, research

How do you search related works for your papers? To be concrete I have implemented few techniques of indirect call promotion for pure C and want to share my results. But at first I want to understand if there are some existing papers about it.

I searched with Google, Google shcolar, citeseerx, microsoft academic search, acm library and semanticscholar. I found only papers on C++ devirtualization but not for pure C. I searched the papers referenced to those what I found but I still did not found anything about pure C.

Can I think my research will be uniqe and interesting for scientific community or I just failed to find existing papers?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351, http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/705

Comment: The tools you are using to search are the ones that you must use. So, now you have to find the best keywords related to your research to look for. I think what you have found about C++ is your related work. Now, is your research unique/interesting? That's we don't know. But one important question you probably should ask yourself is "why do other people in the field did not work with pure C?"

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  This question is probably a better for the [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

This site may also offer you a resource for locating content similar to your paper. Most academic institutions and public libraries have free access to these sorts of research tools to look for published work in selected areas of research. Good Luck.

[Click Here](https://www.lexisnexis.com/start/signin;jsessionid=002385864C99CB37A5AB82F26C48F746.SUBRcnji3w3BwfnQZZdyYg?service=lexis&contractURL=https%3A%2F%2Fw3.lexis.com%2Fresearch2%2FauthResource.do%3F_m%3D7239d6acbf41d27d12f5d1c57ad490ee&key=_c816F0A0B-01EE-DE77-5BB8-38F8E96B2AB6_k170D1F0D-88E2-8068-A592-E10042D787FE&event=form)